# Access JavaScript wrapper properties on html event

Tags: javascript, html, wrapper

Suppose we have some js wrapper object by using we are generating html code. For example we have following closer.

```
function Employee(id, firstName, lastName, salary)
{
   this.id = id;
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;   
   this.salary = salary;
}
```

using above closer object we generated some html code where we set on click event and updated some property of wrapper object but it giving null or undefined script error.

```
var input = $("<div>").on('click', function(){ wrapper.id = 20;})
```

for an example

```
<script>
     var emp = new Employee(1, "vinay", "sharma", 1000000);
     var input = $("<div>").on('click', function(emp){if(emp.id == 1)$("#htmlelement").val("true");})

</script>
```

now if click event occur then emp object is coming null or undefined.

Comment: `$("<div>")` returns `jQuery` object, not `DOMElement`...

Comment: `$("<div>").on('click', function(){ wrapper.id = 20;})`

Comment: Your "wrapper" object doesn't appear to actually wrap anything.

Comment: The the argument **emp** of `$("<div>").on('click', function(emp) ...` overrides the previous `var emp ...`.